# Python selenium Webdriver: How to fixe this error "TimeoutException"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, timeoutexception

I try to use webdriver with chrome but I always have a problem with this error "TimeoutException". I try to use  `WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(lambda x: x.find_element_by_id`. 
I replace 3 with 5 or 10 just for having more times but I'm always blocked. I join a screen of the error:

[image]

I need help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(lambda x: x.find_element_by_xpath
```

=> `xpath` type was mentioned. But it is other type (`id`) from your screenshot.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I was wrong, I wanted to write ```WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(lambda x: x.find_element_by_id('lnk_-831246410')).click()```  as the picture shows

Comment: Do you have idea on how to fix this problem?